# How can I sum up a list of numbers inside a variable which I generated inside a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, loops, sum

I have made a for each loop to access numbers from a JSON array, the array will be dynamic and forever changing and so I have isolated the numbers inside a variable (the variable is inside the loop). My question is: How do I sum up the numbers that are in the variable.

I tried doing a for loop inside the loop but it didn't work.

it looks kind of like this:

```
 const arrayhours = Array.from(json_obj);
 arrayhours.forEach(e=>{ 
              const hours = parseFloat(e.hoursWorked);

console.log(hours); //returns for example 1.25 9 5 8 7 as seperate objects.
});
```

[image: image of console log]

Comment: `let sum = arrayhours.reduce((a, c) => a + +c.hoursWorked, 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for getting sum of numbers in an array.

```
const arrayhours = Array.from(json_obj);
arrayhours.forEach(e=>{ 
  const hours = parseFloat(e.hoursWorked);
  console.log(hours); //returns for example 1.25 9 5 8 7 as seperate objects.
});
const sum = arrayhours.reduce((acc, val) => acc + parseFloat(val.hoursWorked), 0)
```

Comment: That works perfectly, however, I left out one argument, I didn't think it would matter but in this case it does. I have an if argument that narrows down the const "hours" down to hours that are worked inside that period.

arrayhours.forEach(e=>{
    if(e.UnixTimestamp >= startselect && e.UnixTimestamp <= endselect){
     const hours = parseFloat(e.hoursWorked);
 console.log(hours); //returns for example 1.25 9 5 8 7 as seperate objects.
} })
    const sum = arrayhours.reduce((acc, val) => acc + parseFloat(val.hoursWorked), 0)
    console.log(sum); will return sum of entire set in json

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the variable with `let hours = 0` before the loop and then use `+=` to add something (instead of `=`) to assign something.

Finally move the `console.log` out of the loop:

```
const arrayhours = Array.from(json_obj);
let hours = 0;
arrayhours.forEach(e => { 
  const hours += parseFloat(e.hoursWorked);
});
console.log(hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

`const sum = arrayhours.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + parseFloat(curr.hoursWorked, 10), 0)`

In comment, AZ_ is using `+c.hoursWorked` which is a JS trick to cast (if possible) a string into an Int.
It is a pretty bad way to to dit, because not really readable. 
Better use parseInt or parseFloat functions.